# Why do I keep getting bad index files with Git

Tags: hard-drive, git, corruption

I keep getting the following error:

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

And I know the short term solution is just to delete the index and away you go but my question is, why does it keep happening?

I'm not running any kind of utilities over my repo (that i'm aware of) and the hard drive has plenty of disk space.

Since this has happened twice this week, i'm a little concerned. Could this be a sign of HD failure?

(Edit) More Information

The git repo's are on a ubuntu server which I access from OSX via SSH. I also use Sublime text of Samba to access the codebase. I've disable the Sublime text Git plugin which I believe could have been causing the issues. It's not happened since but I don't have any proof either.

Comment: OK, so what's in the server log files?

Comment: Could you be more specific about which logs to look in? I looked in /var/log/syslog but it was quiet empty. I grepped through previous syslogs for "git" but did not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

HDD failure, memory failure, a failure in the I/O components on the mainboard. Better run a bunch of system diagnostics.

What are you running git on? Linux, windows? NFS? Local disk?